# Form pattern is working as expected

Tags: html, forms

can any body tell me what's wrong with my pattern or i am doing some thing else wrong.

```
First have look at the code
```

```html
 <style>
        input:invalid ~ span:before {
                   content: "not good";
               }
               input:valid ~ span:before {
                   content: "good";
               }
               input {
                   display: block;
               }
        </style>
        <form action="">
                <input type="text" 
 pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
        "><span>    </span>
                </form>
```

**For the pattern,** what i want that input field must contain one lower case, one upper case and one number or one special character, i am not sure pattern is right by the way,

So in my head value like this **@9aLkfjakdj** should display me `good`, means my input is correct.

but as soon as i run my code, it try to kill me, it show me `good`, means what the hell their is nothing in the input field why it is saying it all good, and than no matter i typed in the input field it always show me `not good`,

> I basically said in the style that, if input field is correct show me
>   the text good and when it does not show me the text not good,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input type such as `email` or `text` are optional, so that's why the value starts as "good" instead of "not-good".

More info here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/valid/

```html
<style>
    input:invalid ~ span:before {
               content: "not good";
           }
           input:valid ~ span:before {
               content: "good";
           }
           input {
               display: block;
           }
 </style>
 <form action="">
     <input type="text" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" required >
     <span></span>
 </form>
```

Comment: why i should use password as type and what is the different between your pattern and mine ??

Comment: not their is some thing wrong with my pattern as your pattern is working fine,  remove your updated comment, as you are wrong about that, just check your own code, and just leave a comment use this or some thing else and i will accept your solution as your code is working fine,

Comment: i edited your answer my self now i am accepting it. Thanks, accept my edit or edit your self